# Installing memcached php extension

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcache

i have followed countless tutorials and visted dozens of forums on installing the memcached php extension.
I am using the following commands.

```
$ pecl download memcached
$ tar zxvf memcached-1.0.2.tgz
$ cd memcached-1.0.0
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

but when i add the `extension=memcached.so` line in the `php.ini` file memcache will not show up in php info. But the memcache extension (`memcache.so`) will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` file what is the `extension_dir` set to, ensure that the `memcache.so` file is there. Usually it is set to `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/` while your `memcache.so` file ends up in `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-thread-something2010/`. A sym link can solve this quickly.

Turning on `show_startup_errors` may also show something in the log file.

Comment: There is no directory set. i just added memcache.so to the end of the php.ini file and memcache was up and going. What im trying to do is use the memcached.so extension insted but for sme reason i cant intall libmemcached (a dependancy) from pecl.

Comment: /tmp/tmpjAFAid/memcached-1.0.2/php_memcached.c:1949: error: 'instance' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [php_memcached.lo] Error 1
that is the error message i get after i run make install
: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735

: Function eregi() is deprecated in PEAR/Registry.php on line 735
ERROR: `make' failed
[root@nick libmemcached-0.34]#

Comment: Try:`php -m ` to see the extension is truly and successfully loaded.